# Use @Inject ed bean in child class

Tags: java, spring

In spring framework 4.0 I've got a SpecificService inheriting from a GenericService that is Injected with a service. The SpecificService cannot access the Injected service.

Is there a way to make the Injected service accessible from the child class (SpecificService)?

```
// GenericService.java
@Service
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.SUPPORTS, readOnly = true)
public class GenericService {
    @Inject
    OtherService otherService;

    // ...

    private void fn() {
        System.out.println(otherService) // (id = 12)
    }

}

// SpecificService.java 
class SpecificService extends GenericService {

    // ...

    private void fn() {
        System.out.println(otherService) // null
    }

}
```

Comment: Why do you inject a service to another service and another service is a generic service?

Comment: Well with you current example, `SpecificService` is not annotated, so except if it is declared as a bean with XML config it will not define a Spring bean. No injection will occur ...

Comment: Strangely enough adding the annotations to the child class leads to "Application context could not be initialized ..." ... I figured it was because the annotation is also transferred by the `extend` keyword

Comment: Do you ever instantiate the GenericService directly? (i.e. could it be abstract?)

Comment: Regarding the why question: the generic service is extended by several specific services for different specializations that only change a small part of the generic service yet should be treated distinctly.

Comment: I instantiate GenericService if there's no SpecificService that is matched. I could create an additional SpecificService that changes nothing and make GenericService abstract then. How would that help?

Comment: Hmm, that really looks like a x-y problem... Please give some context about the real problem you try to solve that way.

Answer (score 0):

```
// GenericService.java
public abstract class GenericService {

    protected final OtherService otherService;

    public GenericService (OtherService otherService) {
        this.otherService = otherService;
    }

    // ...

    private void fn() {
        System.out.println(otherService) // (id = 12)
    }

}

// SpecificService.java 
@Service
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.SUPPORTS, readOnly = true)
class SpecificService extends GenericService {

    @Inject 
    public SpecificService (OtherService otherService) {
        super(otherService);
    }

    private void fn() {
        System.out.println(otherService) // null
    }

}
```

I'm not 100% this works as I only used Spring 3 with @Autowired, but there I had the same problem and this was the solution. Assuming you can use @Inject on a constructor argument as well.

Comment: unfortunately "The annotation @Inject is disallowed for this location"

Comment: Try @Inject on the constructor in stead of on the parameter

Comment: How would i call that constructor? i.e. what do i pass to it?

Comment: You don't call the constructor, the injection framework does that for you. You just inject SpecificService into other classes.